# Changing variable from inside function without using global

Tags: python-3.x, global-variables

Beginner programmer writing a program that requires a function to alter a variable outside of its scope. I want this function to change this variable without using "global". The issue is a little something like this:

```
tries = 5

def example():

    num = input('Insert number from 0 to 20: ')

    if num != 17:
        global tries
        tries -= 1

        if tries == 0
            print('You lost')
        else:
            print('Wrong number!')
            print('{} tries left!'.format(tries))
            example()

    else:
        print('You win')


example()
```

This is similar to what I am trying to do. Is there any way I can get rid of "global". I keep seeing how this is not a good practice and additionally it shows as a warning every time I run the program, which is not a very good look.

Help?

Comment: Why does it need to change tries outside its scope, will there be another function also using tries at the same time? In this case you could just pass tries into the function. If you need to know how many tries are left afterwards you can return tries back to the main script.

Comment: There will be other function using tries. The script I am writing involves a little more than the example I showed. You are right, in this case I could just pass the variable inside the function, but in case there are other functions also using the variable, is there a way to change the variable without using "global"?

Comment: So you'll be using something like Threading to run multiple functions in parallel with multiple functions consuming tries at the same time? If so you could look at using something like a queue whereby you initialise the queue with 5 tries in it and each time you use a try you get it from the queue. This is perhaps a bit overkill but it is threadsafe. Its also worth noting that mutable types are passed by reference, so if you create a class to represent the number of tries and pass an instance of that class to multiple functions they will all operate on the same instance without use of global